# Selenium webdriver sockettime out exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver, tcp, selenium-iedriver

I am executing a test plan which contains around 117 test cases. This test plan fails randomly in one or the other test case.
Thorows the below exception:

> 2017-03-31 00:17:52,904 ERROR [Log] Error occured during IE browser
>   execution: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out Build info:
>   version: 'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17
>   -0800' System info: host: 'VM-LW-ATAF1', ip: '10.10.70.156', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_121' Driver info: driver.version:
>   InternetExplorerDriver  2017-03-31 03:17:54,303 ERROR [Log] TestCaseID
>   =PSC-2.6,TestStepID =TS107 | Not able to Close the Browser --- java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out Build info: version:
>   'unknown', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:00:17 -0800'
>   System info: host: 'VM-LW-ATAF1', ip: '10.10.70.156', os.name:
>   'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_121' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

As per the inputs from other forums I have increased the MaxUserPort value to high value and TCPTimedWaitDelay to 30 seconds. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you executing all the tests in a single browser session? If not, are you calling quit() after each iteration? Sysout some log text after quit() and check if quit() is getting executing properly.

Comment: Yes. I'm calling quit and its working fine. One clarification will port be allocated each time a selenium command is send? or port is allocated only once while opening the browser?

Comment: Nopes, opening of port is associated with opening a new browser. Have nothing to do with Selenium commands. See your error, it clearly mentions "Not able to Close the Browser --- java.net.SocketTimeoutException". Try to close the opened browsers properly.

Comment: Can you provide some code on how you are trying to close the browser?

Comment: Sorry about "Not able to Close the Browser --" This is a custom error message in my framework. Please ignore  that.

Comment: okay, leaving that apart, we have an error as "SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out". Can you debug and find out on which line is this exception happening & update the HTML DOM of that element along with what action do you want to perform on that element?

Comment: There is no specific step. Its intermittently happening. One thing I noticed is that this happens when I execute from the server machine. Means I have hosted in Windows Server 2008 R2. Does it has something to do with TCP/IP ports getting exhausted if we have both the selenium execution and applciation deployed in same machine?

Comment: definitely the error is related to TCP port/socket. Are you executing through Selenium Grid?

Comment: No. But I am exeucting from the same machine where application is deployed. So I doubt TCP/IP connections are getting exhausted.